# Predictive Model from Counts Data

Tags: mathematical-statistics, modeling, predictive-models, prediction

I have some data that is the number of times a person visited a doctors office over a course of $5$ years. I want to create a model that would be able to predict the most likely number of counts that a person might visit the doctors office.

When I looked at the histogram of the counts distribution I noticed that it was skewed right so I am thinking about going with a poisson model.

My questions are:

1. Is this a good model to predict the number of counts?
2. What other types of models/methods would it be good to look into?
3. Once I have my model how can I test the accuracy?

Any help, comments or references would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Possibly; it's a reasonable first guess for an approximate model. However, even at the level of an individual there's heterogeneity over time (you'd see a doctor more frequently during a period of extended illness or injury, for example), and in groups of individuals, there's sure to be heterogeneity (not everybody is equally well, nor has equal capacity to see a doctor for a given set values on the other variables).
2. You might consider models related to the Poisson that better deal with heterogeneity. quasi-Poisson, negative binomial and Conway-Maxwell Poisson.
3. Are you looking to get some measure of out of sample predictive accuracy?

Comment: By accuracy I just want to know that if I has to present the results to someone how I know myself that I have created a fairly accurate model. It would be also nice to test the accuracy of an out of sample model.

Comment: You explained what you meant by the noun 'accuracy' (in reference to a predictive model) by simply replacing it with it's adjectival form ('accurate'). Can you see that explaining what you intend by defining a word in terms of *itself* cannot really help? So ... what do you mean by the phrase 'accurate model'? Many things might be accurate, and different levels of those things might be accurate do different people or in different circumstances.

Comment: @ Glen_b, yes you are correct. Say I created a model with poisson and I found the Maximum likelihood estimate for counts and I had to present this to an audience. How could I be confident in this estimate if that makes any sense.

Comment: @ Glen_b, I couldn't just say the math behind it shows this, is there tests to check across a subset of the data?

Comment: Are you after a standard error? An interval?

Comment: A standard error

Comment: Of what quantity?

Comment: How would you evaluate this model with an out-of-sample data set? Is it percentage error a valid metric?